# page factory How to verify element?

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I have created an object class for login page and declared login button as:

```
@FindBy(xpath="//*[@id='btnLogin']")
public WebElement loginbutton;
```

Now in my test case i intalillized the login class with Page Factory as:

```
loginPage p = new loginPage(driver);
PageFactory.initElements(driver, p)

p.loginbutton.isDisplayed(); ------> to check if login button is displayed
```

This works fine if the xpath is correct. However, if the xpath is incorrect then it throws an exception and i am unable to catch that exception as the exception is thrown when the page object class is initialized. so the control never reach to the test case. Is there any way handle this situation.

Thanks

Comment: why exception would be thrown when the page object class is initialized , if the xpath is wrong.

Comment: if the xpath of login button is changed then it throws an exception and i want to catch that exception. but i am unable to in PageFactory. Is there any way to catch it

Comment: Are you getting this compile time error : `@FindBy is not allowed in this location `

Comment: How do you know an exception is thrown if you aren't able to catch the exception? ;) My guess is somewhere in your framework you are eating the exception. Also, why are you using XPath to locate an element that is just an ID? Just use the ID. Add a tag for programming language and clarify your question.